Batch Script start Command Ignoring Quotation Marks
I am attempting to make a script in batch (with the help of chatGPT for syntax) to compile C++ programs for me using the VS2022 compiler, and so far my batch script can successfully locate and compile .cpp files, but can't run them for some reason.
I am trying to learn C++ from a textbook, and it has example programs that I try to run, but first need to compile, and therefore I need to constantly open a command window and cl /EHsc the .cpp files to run them.
The code I have so far, for context:
@REM @echo off

:: Set up the Visual Studio environment
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64

:: Prompt for the source directory
:askSourceDirAgain
set /p "source_dir=Enter source directory: "

:: Remove quotes if implemented
set "source_dir=%source_dir:"=%"

if not exist "%source_dir%" (
    echo Directory "%source_dir%" not found, please try again.
    goto askSourceDirAgain
)
echo Source directory found: "%source_dir%"
echo.

:askSourceFileAgain
set /p "source_file=Enter cpp file name: "

:: determine if file name with or without .cpp  provided
set source_file_name=%source_file%
echo %source_file%| findstr /i "\.cpp$" >nul
if errorlevel 1 ( 
    REM if the file does not include .cpp extension
    set "source_file=%source_file%.cpp"
) else (
    for %%F in ("%source_file%") do set "source_file_name=%%~nF"
)

:: verify file exists
if not exist "%source_dir%\%source_file%" (
    echo File "%source_dir%\%source_file%" not found in directory, please try again.
    goto askSourceFileAgain
)
echo File found: "%source_dir%\%source_file%"
echo.

:: compile the program
:recompileProgram
set "output_dir=%source_dir%\Compiled"
if not exist "%output_dir%" (
    echo creating: "%output_dir%"
    mkdir "%output_dir%"
)
echo attempting to compile into: "%output_dir%\%source_file_name%.exe"
pause
cl /EHsc "%source_dir%\%source_file%" /Fe"%output_dir%\%source_file_name%.exe"
echo.

:: ask to run the compiled program
set /p "runProgram=Run the compiled program? (y/n): "
if /i "%runProgram%"=="y" (
    echo attempting to run: "%output_dir%\%source_file_name%.exe"
    start cmd /k "%output_dir%\%source_file_name%.exe"
)
echo.

:: ask the user if they want to recompile, change directory, or exit
:chooseNextStep
echo Choose what to do next
echo 1. Recompile
echo 2. Choose another program to compile
echo 3. Choose another directory and compile another program
echo 4. Exit
set /p choice="Choice: "

if "%choice%"=="1" (
    goto recompileProgram
) else if "%choice%"=="2" (
    goto askSourceFileAgain
) else if "%choice%"=="3" (
    goto askSourceDirAgain
) else if "%choice%"=="4" (
    exit /b 0
) else (
    echo Invalid response, please try again.
    goto chooseNextStep
)

The problem I am having is specifically with the start cmd /k "%output_dir%\%source_file_name%.exe" line. I am trying to get it so that it prompts the user if they want to run the compiled .cpp file, and then if the user chooses to run the compiled script, it will run and show the output of the program. Part of the problem of running these scripts, however, is that they're typically short, simple programs that don't feature a pause, so they finish running quickly and then the cmd window closes immediately.
So effectively the behavior I am looking for is:

User inputs parameters
Program is compiled
Batch asks to run compiled program
User chooses yes
Batch opens a new cmd window and runs the program
The new cmd window finishes running the compiled program and waits for the user to close it

The big problem I have right now is that the batch script ignores the quotation marks in the file path provided.
For additional context:
Folder of .cpp file: Z:\Documents\Projects\Programming\00 -- TESTING & LEARNING\C++\Textbook Learning\Chapter 08 - Arrays and Vectors
File name: Program 8-32.cpp
Folder of compiled, .exe file: Z:\Documents\Projects\Programming\00 -- TESTING & LEARNING\C++\Textbook Learning\Chapter 08 - Arrays and Vectors\Compiled
Program echo:
attempting to compile into: "Z:\Documents\Projects\Programming\00 -- TESTING & LEARNING\C++\Textbook Learning\Chapter 08 - Arrays and Vectors\Compiled\program 8-32.exe"
Press any key to continue . . .
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.29.30154 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

program 8-32.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.29.30154.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

"/out:Z:\Documents\Projects\Programming\00 -- TESTING & LEARNING\C++\Textbook Learning\Chapter 08 - Arrays and Vectors\Compiled\program 8-32.exe"
"program 8-32.obj"

Run the compiled program? (y/n): y
attempting to run: "Z:\Documents\Projects\Programming\00 -- TESTING & LEARNING\C++\Textbook Learning\Chapter 08 - Arrays and Vectors\Compiled\program 8-32.exe"

Choose what to do next
1. Recompile
2. Choose another program to compile
3. Choose another directory and compile another program
4. Exit
Choice:

It opens a new cmd window with the response:
'Z:\Documents\Projects\Programming\00' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
The system cannot find the path specified.

I will note that I have also tried the following:

start cmd /k ""%output_dir%\%source_file_name%.exe"" adding additional quotes does nothing, it just repeats the same problem as above.

start cmd /k ("%output_dir%\%source_file_name%.exe") adding parentheses opens a new cmd window, but closes it immediately upon opening. It appears to open without text and immediately close.


I will note that I am very inexperienced with batch scripting, and most of this is with chatGPT's help and my general understanding of syntax rules from other languages. I've heard to use REM in place of ::, but that's for another time.

I will commend that for some reason, after asking chatGPT,
cd /d "%output_dir%" & start "" cmd /k "%source_file_name%.exe"
(assuming I'm using the & correctly here, where it's separating two different lines) fixes and runs the batch script as I originally envisioned, where it actually ran the program and waited for me to close it. For some reason this implementation doesn't ignore the quotation marks in the file path yet the original implementation does...

Try start "hello there" cmd /k … Start eats the first quoted parameter as the window title, so always use an explicit title as the first quoted parameter. That title can be empty ("") but should not be omitted

@Magoo If only I could mark your comment, writing in start "%source_file_name%" cmd /k "%output_dir%\%source_file_name%.exe" seems to have actually worked like you mentioned. EDIT: nevermind, it appears that doesn't fix the problem in the original script

For future reference: This is far too much code to include to ask about a single line. Please review [mre] to be aware of what our expectations are before your next question. It's unreasonable to ask us to filter out all the irrelevant code to isolate the problem area - that's something you should be doing in advance of posting here.

@KenWhite I was attempting to provide the full script merely for reference, but I had focused the problem down on to the specific line after providing the full script, in that I was having trouble with one specific line. Maybe I was being too verbose, but I will keep it in mind for the future.

There was far too much code. I had to read it twice before I found the line you mentioned. I should have been able to do with a quick scan. Posting the absolute minimum amount of code needed to demonstrate the issue helps us to help you - it's usually not worth exerting the effort of wading through large quantities of code trying to isolate a line or two. There's a reason that the [mre] post was published here. Please follow its guidelines, for both your sake (in getting answers more quickly, if at all) and ours (for time and effort purposes - we're volunteers, not paid staff).

As an addition to my previous comments, the requirement to provide the fewest lines possible when asking for debugging help is part of the official site guidelines in the [help/on-topic], which also reference that [mre] post.

After asking the same question on Reddit The problem I found was simply that the directory was not stated. As per the SS64 start documentation I have been provided, I needed to implement a directory for the command to find the program for some reason.
In short, instead of
start "%source_file_name%" cmd /k "%source_file_name%.exe"
I needed to specify the directory as such
start "%source_file_name%" /d "%output_dir%" cmd /k "%source_file_name%.exe"
